# Appcelerator Apps don't work in Firefox and Chrome but work in IE

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I have problem as following. I use a Titanium Studio, build: 3.1.1.201306112235 with SDK 3.1.1 GA (on Windows 7). When I try to run example app as "Mobile Web Preview in Browser", then I saw mobile app in my Firefox (version 21.0) but any actions associated with 'clicks' don't work. Furthermore when I try run the same app in Chrome I see the same behaviour. Only in Internet Explorer app works properly (version 10). Do you have idea why apps from Titanium don't work properly? If you would like to get some more logs just ask.

EDIT: I provide remote access, and reopen page by Firefox in the same version on my colleague's laptop. Then in here browser everything works well. So i have question which settings, on my browser can "freezing" titanium application. Javascript is running, so I don't have idea, what is bad in my configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you are making web service calls to a remote host, which violates the same-origin-policy built into recent versions of chrome.

Try opening up chrome with this policy disabled:

`chrome.exe --disable-web-security`

Comment: I try your sollution, but unfortunately it don't work for me.